# Redirecting Urls via PHP without htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect my urls but not with htaccess, only with php. I know that I have to use the `header()` function. But my question is how to catch the url.

For example, Wordpress catches urls like `mysite.com/postname` and redirects it to other urls, I think it is `index.php?parameters=values`.

But my question how to catch the url `mysite.com/postname` and redirect it to other. Which php script will catch it.

Or when wordpress catch the url, which php file redirects it to `index.php`

Comment: I think it's better to post that in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I am using StackOverFlow android app

Comment: @IvankaTodorova — The question isn't about Wordpress. It's a generic server configuration question (although it thinks it is a PHP question) that uses Wordpress as an example of what is desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your HTTP server that the URL is handled by the PHP script.

You can't do this with PHP directly: If the server never runs the PHP script, then the PHP script can't do anything with the request!

This is most commonly done with [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which is configured using Apache configuration. There are two basic places that you can put `mod_rewrite` directives.

- The main Apache configuration files
- A [`.htaccess` file](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html).

The former is recommended:

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

… and you've rejected `.htaccess` so put the directives in your main configuration file.

---

This, of course, assumes you are using Apache HTTPD. You didn't say which HTTP server you were using.

---

This also assumes that when you rejected `.htaccess` you didn't mean `mod_rewrite`. Many people conflate the two since changes to `mod_rewrite` settings are the most common things that programmers (as opposed to System Administrators) want to do in an Apache configuration.

---

> For example, Wordpress catches urls like mysite.com/postname and redirects it to other urls

Wordpress uses `mod_rewrite` directives in a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thank you Quentin.
Can I know how WordPress catch the url at mysite.com/postname without an htaccess file.
I used wordpress in xampp and it works fine.
I thought it won't run in httpd server of my android device because it redirect and redirect must need htaccess.
When i saw it works and redirects well than I questioned

Comment: See the last line of my answer. (I double checked and my WordPress installs all have a `.htaccess` file with `mod_rewrite` directivew in it).